# How do I obtain a GDrive access token without using a library?

Tags: google-oauth

There seems to be very little information about getting started with Google's Drive REST API, besides the Quickstarts section (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/about-sdk). I am trying to use their API in AutoIt, but I can't seem to find out how to generate an access token without using one of the available quickstart libraries. I am aware of the REST API docs (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/), but still, can't find anything about generating the access token. I have already generated a Client ID and a Client Secret though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Which language? Can you use Service Account credentials instead of OAuth2?

Answer (score 0):

Google's OAuth endpoints can be used with any library (or you could roll your own, but there are plenty of quality libraries). There is plenty of documentation of [OAuth2 at Google](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), and there is the [OAuth2 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/) where you can experiment with OAuth and the Google APIs.

If you have a library, Google's OAuth endpoints are available in the OpenIdConnect discovery doc at https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration